# How to get free demo parts from manufactures?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, integrated-circuit, pid-controller

I've heard about people getting free parts from manufactures. I'm curious if anyone can point me in the right direction for how to do this.

I'm looking to get free parts so I can make an inverted pendulum. If I don't have to pay for parts, that'll make it even better for me.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic. Its a question on how/where to "buy" components (even if the price is "Zero").

Comment: Have a credible and fully-financed plan to buy a few hundred thousand (or more) pieces and the world's your oyster. They may even do your design or provide code for you.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is dream on. Manufacturers are cracking down on who they hand out engineering samples to. If you don't have a company, or maybe .edu, email address, it's a pretty good indicator they have no incentive to give you anything. They want to get their engineering samples into the hands of people that can actually use them to develop a commercial product and drive sales.

Answer (score 1):

The intention of sample programs is to quickly (most samples ship 2-day, or faster) get parts into hands of engineers for them to test, and then hopefully design into a product, resulting in a PO for 10,000 units at the end of it. These sample programs also somewhat pre-date the easy ordering of single quantity parts from distributors like Mouser, Newark and Digi-Key.

Some companies have a history of supporting college students and projects, for similar reasons -- Microchip used to (might still be) really good about sending you free PICs if you requested with an .edu mail address and explained it was for your project, as you might go on to become an engineer who chooses a PIC for their next volume project.

In my opinion, I'd say it's kind of a lame move to leverage manufacturers for a hobby project like that based on samples. With sites like Digi-Key around that will sell you a part in quantity 1 if you want, I don't think there's a valid reason to /need/ to sample parts (besides them being pre-production).

I don't want to jump down your throat for trying to get free parts, because I definitely sampled parts as a student for my senior projects. I have however designed in parts from certain brands that took care of me as a student for products that have shipped large volume, so it ended up paying off for them in the end.